# Cross-origin request to glitch.me server

Tags: node.js, cors, glitch-framework

I have created a server on glitch.me and I am trying to serve data from the server but the following error came up.
localhost/:1 Access to fetch at 'https://clem-quote-server.glitch.me/quotes' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
>   mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Not really sure how to resolve this

```
import React, {Component} from "react"

class quotes extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            error: null,
            isLoaded: false,
            quotes: quotes
        };
    }

componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://clem-quote-server.glitch.me/quotes")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
            this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
              quotes: result.quotes
          });
        },
        error => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      );
}

    render() {
        const { error, isLoaded, quotes } = this.state;
        if (error) {
            return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
        } else if (!isLoaded) {
            return <div>Loading...</div>;
        } else {
            return (
              <ul>
                {quotes.map(quote => {
                    return quote;

                }  
                )}
              </ul>
            );
        }
    }
}       
    export default quotes;
```

I want to be able to display one object from the list of the array each time the page loads

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38500226/441757 and other answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/how-to-allow-cors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is failing because of CORS, which have to be included when different domains are handled by the server and client.

CORS are included on the headers.

Here's how you would enable corse in your react app:

https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development

CORS info:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS